# fullcalendar cannot display event

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar

Fullcalendar is not showing the events fetched by ajax. The events is successfully passed because I can display it by pop up but it is not showing in the calendar. The fullcalendar will show events if i manually set the events but once i use the data pass from .cs file it cannot render.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;

namespace TravelPlannerO
{
    public partial class Schedule : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public class Event
        {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string start { get; set; }
        public string end { get; set; }
        public string desc { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }

        public Event(string id, string title, string start, string end,string desc,string status)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
            this.desc = desc;
            this.status = status;
        }
        };


        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetEvent()
        {
            string strSelect;
            SqlCommand cmdSelect;
            SqlDataReader dtr;
            SqlConnection conn;
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["plannerdb"].ConnectionString;
            conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

            strSelect = "Select * from [Source.SavedPlan]";

            cmdSelect = new SqlCommand(strSelect, conn);
            conn.Open();
            dtr = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();
```

```js
<script src="Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
        
<script type="text/javascript">

    var listofevent;
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
       left: 'prev,next today',
       center: 'title',
       right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
       },
    events:function (id,title,start, end, callback) {
       $.ajax({
       type: "POST ",
       url: '<%=Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrl.Resolve(" /Schedule.aspx / GetEvent ")%>',
       data: {},
       contentType: "application / json;charset = utf - 8 ",
       dataType: "json ",
       success: function (list) {
        listofevent = list.d;
        alert(listofevent);
        var events = [];
        alert(list.d);
        var obj = $.parseJSON(list.d);
        console.log(obj);
           
      $(list).find('event').each(function () {   
       events.push({
       title: $(this).attr('title'),
       start: $(this).attr('start'),
       end: $(this).attr('end') 
        });
       console.log(obj.calEvent);
         });
       //callback(events);
       callback && callback(events);
        },
       error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
         }
         }); 
        },
        defaultDate: '2015-1-1',
        selectable: true,
        editable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "
more " link when too many events
                  </script>
```

```css
<link href="Content/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <link href="Content/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" /> <link href="Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

```html
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

```
            List<object> array = new List<object>();

            if (dtr.HasRows)
            {
                var index_id = dtr.GetOrdinal("PlanId");
                var index_title = dtr.GetOrdinal("Name");
                var index_start = dtr.GetOrdinal("DateFrom");
                var index_end = dtr.GetOrdinal("DateTo");
                var index_desc = dtr.GetOrdinal("Description");
                var index_status = dtr.GetOrdinal("Status");


                while (dtr.Read())
                {
                var id = dtr.GetValue(index_id).ToString();
                var title = dtr.GetValue(index_title).ToString();
                var datestart = dtr.GetValue(index_start).ToString();
                var dateend = dtr.GetValue(index_end).ToString();
                var desc = dtr.GetValue(index_desc).ToString();
                var status = dtr.GetValue(index_status).ToString();

                DateTime RealStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datestart);
                DateTime RealEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateend);
                string start = RealStartDate.ToString("s");
                string end = RealEndDate.ToString("s");

                Event eventrows = new Event(id, title, start, end,desc,status);

                array.Add(eventrows);   
                }
            }
            string myJsonString = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(array);
            return myJsonString;
        }
        private static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
        {
            var origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my visual studio there are no spaces between the  I think I might accidentally space it while I paste it here. I dont understand why the events is not showing. While i print 'list.d' from success: function(list), the result is 
[{"id:"1","title":"testoh","start":"2015-01-01T00:00:00","end":"2015-01-02T00:00:00","desc":"abaaba","status":"first    "},
[{"id:"2","title":"okok","start":"2015-05-01T00:00:00","end":"2015-05-02T00:00:00","desc":"fdgd","status":"second    "}]
Is the format correct?. I noticed my callback function is not called but i dunno why

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by editing the argument in the `events:function (id,title,start, end, callback)` to `events:function (start, end,timezone, callback)`. btw thanks for the reply..